# Swift How to process multiple button UI elegantly?

Tags: swift

In my viewController I need to process button UI

I think my approach to process UI is not efficient

What if someday I need to do more button?

Today I just happen to have only three.....

Just want user press one of three, and others keep original color

like make user feel which one they press in many button

Here's my @IBAction

```
@IBAction func btnPress (_ sender: UIButton) {
        let clickedBackgroundColor = UIColor(red: 1, green: 153, blue: 202, a: 1)
        let clickedTextColor = UIColor(red: 255, green: 255, blue: 255, a: 1)
        let originBackgroundColor = UIColor(red: 216, green: 247, blue: 250, a: 1)
        let originTextColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 71, blue: 88, a: 1)

        switch sender {
        case btnA:
            btnA.backgroundColor = clickedBackgroundColor
            btnA.setTitleColor(clickedTextColor, for: .normal)
            btnA.underline()

            btnB.backgroundColor = originBackgroundColor
            btnB.setTitleColor(originTextColor, for: .normal)
            btnC.backgroundColor = originBackgroundColor
            btnC.setTitleColor(originTextColor, for: .normal)


        case btnB:
            btnB.backgroundColor = clickedBackgroundColor
            btnB.setTitleColor(clickedTextColor, for: .normal)
            btnB.underline()

            btnA.backgroundColor = originBackgroundColor
            btnA.setTitleColor(originTextColor, for: .normal)
            btnC.backgroundColor = originBackgroundColor
            btnC.setTitleColor(originTextColor, for: .normal)


        case btnC:
            btnC.backgroundColor = clickedBackgroundColor
            btnC.setTitleColor(clickedTextColor, for: .normal)
            btnC.underline()

            btnA.backgroundColor = originBackgroundColor
            btnA.setTitleColor(originTextColor, for: .normal)
            btnB.backgroundColor = originBackgroundColor
            btnB.setTitleColor(originTextColor, for: .normal)

        default:break
        }
    }
```

And My UIButton Extension for adding underline

I can only add underline but how to remove it if user click other button?

```
extension UIButton {
    func underline() {
        guard let text = self.titleLabel?.text else { return }
        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text)
        attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.underlineStyle, value: NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: text.count))
        self.setAttributedTitle(attributedString, for: .normal)
    }
}
```

I'm really new, not good at questioning if need more info just ask for me, Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply can create an **`Outlet Collection`** for all `buttons` instead of explicitly creating an `array` of `buttons` and use that to set the `button's` properties as per the selection, i.e.

```
@IBOutlet var buttons: [UIButton]!
```

**Usage:**

```
@IBAction func btnPress (_ sender: UIButton) {
    let clickedBackgroundColor = UIColor(red: 1, green: 153, blue: 202, a: 1)
    let clickedTextColor = UIColor(red: 255, green: 255, blue: 255, a: 1)
    let originBackgroundColor = UIColor(red: 216, green: 247, blue: 250, a: 1)
    let originTextColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 71, blue: 88, a: 1)

    buttons.forEach { (button) in
        button.backgroundColor = (button == sender) ? clickedBackgroundColor : originBackgroundColor
        button.setTitleColor((button == sender) ? clickedTextColor : originTextColor, for: .normal)
        if button == sender {
            button.underline()
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** Also, there is no need to traverse the `array` twice. `One single traversal` will work fine.